# Angularjs Error as is not a function

Tags: angularjs

Please help me why i'm Getting Login_Fac.GetData is not a function/

```
app.controller('LoginCtrls', function ($scope, Login_Fac, $window) {
    $scope.GetToken = function () {
            Login_Fac.GetData().then(function (d) {
                alert('success...')
            }).catch(function () {
                alert('error...')
            })
```

**factory.js**

```
app.factory('Login_Fac', function ($http, $window) {
    var LoginScredential = {};
 LoginScredential.GetData = function () {
         return $http({
             url: 'http://localhost:63252/api/department',
         })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your factory as,

```
factories.factory('Login_Fac', function ($http, $window) {
    var LoginScredential = {
        GetData: () => {
            return $http({
                url: 'http://localhost:63252/api/department',
            })
        },
    };

    return LoginScredential;
});
```